# Is there a subgroup of the general linear group isomorphic to the general linear group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over some field $K$. (Let us consider the case $K$ is characteristic 0 and the dimension of V is greater than one )

Is there a proper subgroup of $GL( \mathbb{V})$ isomorphic to $GL( \mathbb{V})$? Also, the same question for  $SL( \mathbb{V})$.

If you do not know the answer, please give any idea/reference on approaching to the problem. My intuition is the answer is no, but I could not show it.

Comment: If $K$ is finite then obviously the answer is 'no'. If $K=\mathbb Q$ and $V$ is $1$-dimensional then $GL(V)$ is simply $\mathbb Q^\times$, and this is just isomorphic to a countable direct product of copies of $\mathbb Z$. In this case the answer is therefore 'yes'.

Comment: @David: a countable direct sum, together with a copy of $C_2$, but that doesn't affect the argument. The question for $SL$ seems much harder though.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly the question,but group isomorphism is an equivalence relation and thus it is reflexive,meaning that every group is isomorphic to itself

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Do you have any comment on the case, dimension greater than one and field is characteristic zero? Maybe I should have asked the question like that in the beginning...

Comment: @MhdBhsn I'm pretty sure that the OP meant "isomorphic to $GL(\mathbb{V})$" rather than "isomorphic to itself". But you're right about what they actually wrote.

Comment: Yes... @JeremyRickard. I edited.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I forgot about the $C_2$, this is true and thanks. The direct sum versus direct product argument is dependent on subject, and has been litigated on this site before. The categorical direct sum is often called direct product and the categorical direct product is often called Cartesian product or unrestricted product. It's unhelpful, but true.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}$ has a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, surely the answer is 'yes' for all dimensions?

Comment: @David: ah, yep, that'll do it!

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you, for your example. Do you have another, let me say non-trivial, example which is not coming from an isomorphic subfield? Like in the case of $GL(n, \mathbb{Q})$.